# navigation drawer is not tall enough

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

[image]

I created a navigation drawer in my app, but as you can see in the image above, the navigation drawer is too short and it is only long enough to contain the existing items.

My codes looks like:

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ykim164cs242.tournamentor.UserMainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/nav_layout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**navigation_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group>
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_select_channel"
            android:title="Select Channel"
            android:icon="@mipmap/channel_icon"/>

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_team_list"
            android:title="Team List"
            android:icon="@mipmap/team_logo"/>

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_league_status"
            android:title="League Status"
            android:icon="@mipmap/league_status_icon"/>
    </group>

</menu>
```

I am not sure this happened because the background is dark, but I at least want it to fill the whole height of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just make navigation view height to **match_parent** and width to **wrap_content** or give some value.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header">
```